Prove $\frac{2e^{-2y}}{1 + e^{-2y}} \le\lvert \cot z + 1 \rvert \le\frac{2e^{-2y}}{1 - e^{-2y}}$ for $y=\operatorname{Im}(z)>0,x=\operatorname{Re}(z)$
Help me prove the following inequality:
$$
\frac{2e^{-2y}}{1 + e^{-2y}} \leq \lvert \cot z + 1 \rvert \leq \frac{2e^{-2y}}{1 - e^{-2y}}, \quad (y > 0),
$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $ x = \operatorname{Re}(z) $, and $ y = \operatorname{Im}(z) $.
So far, I have tried representing $\cot z$ using its complex form:
$$
\cot z = i \frac{e^{2iz} + 1}{e^{2iz} - 1},
$$
but I am struggling to simplify and obtain the bounds involving $ e^{-2y} $. Any hints or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541630/42969
